# Why is member look-up not allowed in return types of out-of-line definitions?

Tags: c++, parsing, compilation, language-lawyer, c++98

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct T {
    using iterator = int*;
    iterator begin() const;
    iterator end() const;
    /* ... */
};

// OK, member look-up allowed in trailing return types (since C++11)
auto T::begin() const -> iterator { /* ... */ }

// error: iterator does not name a type
iterator T::end() const { /* ... */ }
```

**What is the rationale** for making the second form impossible? It would obviously be useful if we could refer to the names of members in the return type. C++11 has remedied this somewhat, but what about C++98, or pre-standard *"C with classes"*?

I understand that it would require some form of look-ahead, since the parser cannot understand `iterator` until it has parsed `T::end()`. It shouldn't break compatibility with C, since C doesn't have out-of-line members, so we could implement this any way we want.

Is this too difficult for the compiler to implement -and if so, why-, or is it simply a design decision?

Comment: What should happen if the type `iterator` exists in that outer scope?  Which `iterator` should be used then?

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike the same thing that happens when you use `iterator` in a trailing return type or other context where unqualified member look-up is allowed: it would refer to `T::iterator` because it shadows `::iterator`. I'm unsure if this introduces a parsing ambiguity if `T::iterator` is a type, but `::iterator` is not. Only declarations are allowed at namespace scope, so this might be okay.

Comment: In general, C++ doesn't have name lookup that finds names not yet introduced. Likewise, you can use parameter names in trailing return types but not non-trailing. (Complete class contexts being an exception.)

Comment: I am not sure whether it applies here, but you can't really delay doing name lookup for almost anything in C++ until a later point in the source code because parsing pretty much any C++ is strongly context-dependent. For example whether or not a `<` in the supposed return type is going to introduce a nested template argument list until the next closing `>` is dependent on performing name lookup for the name before the `<`. Depending on the result the sequence of tokens matching the return type may differ.

Comment: Inside templates this only works with complex rules for dependent names and with the user indicating parsing behavior with the `typename` and `template` keywords. I don't think you'd want that in every declaration.

Comment: @user17732522 expressions cannot appear at namespace scope and we can only define members out-of-line at namespace scope. Therefore, we can always parse `iterator<T>` as a template instead of an expression with lower-than/greater-than operators. We would need to delay the unqualified name lookup until reading `T::end()`, but otherwise there are no problems.

Comment: @JanSchultke Expressions can appear as non-type template arguments, e.g. `A<B<C>` can be a complete template-id for the template `A` or a partial template-id where the first `<` has no closing `>` depending on whether lookup for `B` finds a template. It is not obvious to me that you could always distinguish where the return type ends and the declarator-id starts without doing any lookup in the return type.

Comment: @user17732522 okay yeah, that pretty much answers the question (and I'd accept it as an answer). That's a concrete example of where we need arbitrary look-ahead, and that's enough of an issue to not allow the second syntax.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think parsing C++ requires arbitrary lookahead anyway (ignoring implementation limits), so I am not sure how valid a reason that alone would be. In the worst case you can't distinguish arbitrarily long statements from being declarations or expression-statements until the very end due to the parentheses ambiguity, which is only resolved by an explicit rule that says interpretation as declaration is preferred if otherwise ambiguous.

Comment: @user17732522 that's a valid concern. But what you've mentioned might be full parsing ambiguity: If our template-id ends with `C > T::end()`, how can we distinguish between declaring the `T::end()` function and comparing greater-than with the result of calling it?, if we don't know what `C` means? It seems like infinite look-ahead without the ability to tell where to stop.

Comment: @JanSchultke That's why I was careful, only posting a comments. I couldn't come up with a full member function definition (for declarations it shouldn't matter, because member functions can't be redeclared except in a defintion) that could be fully ambiguous under your suggested rules on the spot, but it doesn't seem unlikely to me that it is possible either.

Comment: @user17732522: No, you have the whole answer.  These function definitions can occur only at namespace scope, so there is no statement ambiguity and counting “non-nested” `>`s is enough to know when the declarator begins.